# How to drag selected item of p:selectOneListBox and drop into p:inputTextarea?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here is my code:

```
 <p:selectOneListbox id="columnName"
                        widgetVar="columnName"
                        value="#{dataTransformBean.column}">

        <f:selectItems id="itemDrop"
                       value="#{dataTransformBean.columnList}"
                       var="item" itemValue="#{item}" />

        <p:ajax update="textarea" />
    </p:selectOneListbox>

    <p:inputTextarea  id="textarea" rows="6" cols="33" />

    <p:selectOneListbox id="function"
                        widgetVar="function"
                        value="#{dataTransformBean.function}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{dataTransformBean.functionValNames}" />
    </p:selectOneListbox>

    <p:draggable for="columnName" revert="true" helper="clone"></p:draggable>
```

I want to drag only selected item of `<p:selectOneListBox>` in `<p:inputTextarea>` for which `for="id"` which drags whole list box..How can I drag only selected item from list.

Comment: Is there a drag-drop feature in case of p:selectOneListBox in jsf primefaces? I have searched but I got this only for datatables

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Drag & Drop - Custom" example in the showcase
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/custom.xhtml

In this example, it defines the class ".ui-treenode-leaf" to be draggable and class ".ui-datatable .droppoint" to be droppable.

(I guess) In the case of p:selectOneListBox, you can try to define "ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" as draggable. So only the selected (highlight'ed) selectlistbox item will be draggable. Of course you should also define p:inputTextarea as your droppable and create p:remoteCommands with necessary action listeners in the bean.

Comment: I tried doing same but actionListener of p:remoteCommand is not getting called due to which js is also not called. There is a example given on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml in which a method onclick="rc()" is called on click of p:commandButton. I guess this is missing